# Install python 2.7 with no gcc installed

Tags: python, python-2.7, gcc, centos6.5

I have a CentOS 6.5 server with python 2.6 and a restriction on updating kernel. I need to configure virtualenv for a django 1.8 project to run.

As soon as django 1.8 works at least with python 2.7, I need it to be installed also. Installation of python requires gcc to compile python binaries. When I try to install gcc with `yum install gcc`, I get following errors:

```
Error: Package: glibc-headers-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: kernel-headers >= 2.2.1
Error: Package: glibc-headers-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: kernel-headers
```

Is there any other way to install python without gcc and not updating kernel? I can't do it due to other soft requirements.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install a compatible CentOS 6.5 on another computer. Install all necessary packages to develop Python 2.7.

Compile Python there.

Copy the compiled tree to the original server.

Run `make install`.